# Connecting to TLS through Jmeter using MQTT publisher

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, tls1.2

I am trying to publish event through MQTT publisher. In the provider URL have mentioned tls://URL:Port

When I am trying to execute it gives below error:. I am using apache jmeter 5.0 and MQTT jar versiion : mqtt-jmeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tls://**.***.****.***:1887
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:470)
[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.(MqttAsyncClient.java:273)
[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.(MqttAsyncClient.java:167) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.(MqttClient.java:224) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mqtt.paho.clients.BlockingClient.(BlockingClient.java:81) ~[mqtt-jmeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mqtt.sampler.PublisherSampler.initClient(PublisherSampler.java:247) ~[mqtt-jmeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mqtt.sampler.PublisherSampler.sample(PublisherSampler.java:271) ~[mqtt-jmeter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]

Comment: Does ssl:// instead of tls:// work ?

Comment: When i replaced tls with ssl, got below error:
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:604) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar:?]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

I think for MQTT you have the choice of `tcp, ssl, ws and wss` (the latter 2 are for MQTT over [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) transport)  so my expectation is that **you need to use `ssl`**, not `tls`

Also it appears that you're using quite an [outdated plugin](https://github.com/hemikak/mqtt-jmeter) which missing some essential features (like sending client-side certificates), maybe it would be a better idea to consider using [xmeter-mqtt](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter#mqtt-protocol) plugin? See [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide) article for more information.

Comment: I installed latest plugin as mentioned above. Selected protocols : SSL, checked dual SSL certification , selected .crt extension certificate.  secret field kept BLANK. and tried but got below error:

Failed to establish Connection. Please check SSL authentication info.